# How to process multiple text files at a time to analysis using mapreduce in hadoop

Tags: file, hadoop, input, merge, mapreduce

I have lots of small files , say more than 50000. i need to process these files at a time using map reduce concept to generate some analysis based on the input files.

Please suggest me a way to do this and also please let me know how to merge this small files into a big file using hdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) from cloudera explaining the problem with small files.

There is a [project](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/filecrush) in github named FileCrush which does merge large number of small files. From project's homepage:

> Turn many small files into fewer larger ones. Also change from text to sequence and other compression options in one pass.